# Prove that $0\le a^2 < b^2$ implies $a < b$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Q) $a$ and $b$ are positive real numbers and $a^2 < b^2$. Prove that $a < b$

My working so far: Assuming always that $a, b > 0$, the contrapositive of $$a^2 < b^2 \implies a < b$$ is

$$a \ge b \implies a^2 \ge b^2\;.$$

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

HINT: Multiply $a\ge b$ by $a$ to get $a^2\ge ab$ and by $b$ to get $ab\ge b^2$.

Comment: next step: combine, so a^2 > ba > b^2 And a = b implies a^2 = b^2.
So together combining gives a≥b and a^2≥b^2.

Is this correct?

Comment: @DeeDee: You’ve got it.

Comment: YES, Thanks for the hint.

Comment: @DeeDee: You’re very welcome.

Answer (score 5):

A more direct approach.

If $a,b>0$, then $a+b>0$, and hence $\frac{1}{a+b}>0$.

If $a^2<b^2$ then $$0 < b^2-a^2 = (b-a)(b+a)$$

Multiply both sides by $\frac{1}{a+b}$ to get $$0< b-a$$ so $a<b$.

This shows that you only really need $a+b>0$ and $b^2>a^2$ to show $b>a$.

Comment: Your contrapositive approach works, as the other answers show, I just liked this answer as a direct approach. (A contrapositive prove is essentially a proof by contradiction, hence sometimes referred to as "indirect.")

Answer (score 4):

$b\le a $ $\implies$ $b^2\le ab\le a^2$

Comment: next step: combine, so a^2 > ba > b^2 And a = b implies a^2 = b^2.
So together combining gives a≥b and a^2≥b^2.

Is this correct?

Comment: @DeeDee edited the question. helped you?

Comment: Yes, thank you.

Comment: @DeeDee  $b^2\le a^2$ is already a contradiction. because your assuption is $a^2<b^2$. So you can conclude that you can not have $b\le a$. Therefore $a<b$

Answer (score 1):

I solve it in this way

if $a < b$

by multiplying both side by $a$ .. we get $a^2 < a.b$

,, also by multiplying both side by $b$ .. we get $a.b < b^2$

now we have $a^2 < a.b < b^2$
So $a^2 < b^2$

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), 
[here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and 
[here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: okey thanks.. i will check it

Answer (score 0):

This might not be considered a formal proof but it is convincing (because of tis geometrical nature) plus generalises the fact to $(a^n < b^n \Rightarrow a < b \hspace{.5cm} \forall n \in \mathbb{N})$

Think of "$a^n < b^n$" as "the n-volume of a n-cube of side $a$ is smaller than the n-volume of a n-cube of side $b$"

This, as we are talking of n-cubes, certainly means that the n-cube with less volume fits into the other (imagine them sharing one corner) and so the side of the smaller one fits into the side of the bigger one which means $a<b$.

Answer (score 0):

I know you probably want a trivial proof. But you can see this way: what you want is basically
 proof that $\sqrt{x}$ is crescent . The derived is positive $\implies$ $\sqrt{x}$ crescent